# "sh Command not found" and "invalid payload"

Tags: python, shell, trojan

I'm writing a trojan for a school project and it asked for a rb implant to be created.
when I run the command it says that both the implant.sh command is not found and that the payload is invalid. I'm running the program on Kali Linux and following the book word for word but nothing has seemed to work

```
implant.sh | msfvenom --payload --arch x86 --platform --encoder bash/bash_base64 -o implant encoded
```

results:

```
implant.sh: command not found
Error: invalid payload --arch
```

Comment: Use `./implant.sh` to run a script that's located in your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

When you're executing a script in a Unix environment you must prefix it with "./"

It is important to note that the script also needs execution permission, which you can give to the script by doing
"chmod +x implant.sh"

Comment: I added the correct characters and implemented the permission however the arch is still not accepted as a payload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412411/error-you-must-select-an-arch-for-a-custom-payload